# Dynamically generate tickboxes combined with a search in using jupyter widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I've built a jupyter notebook to analyse and contrast historical data. Because the database is quite large I used a search + observe widget to allow the user to select the experiments they want rather than scroll through all the data. Right now all the checkboxes for all the experiments are generated but this is both too big to fit into the box and takes up a lot of time.

Is there a way to show only the last 10 experiments by default AND only generate the needed checkboxes after a search?

i based the code on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pbugnion/5bb7878ff212a0116f0f1fbc9f431a5c). I already tried to move the checkbox widget inside of the else loop but that did not work. In addition the global/local variable situation seems muddled in my code.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

#Generate a dummy list
Allfileslist = ["Experiment {}".format(x) for x in range(600)]
#Search box + generate ALL the checkboxes, this seems to be the bottleneck
search_widget = widgets.Text(placeholder='Type for older experiments',                 description= 'Search:')
experiments = {eachfilename: widgets.Checkbox(description=eachfilename, value=False) for eachfilename in Allfileslist}
options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in Allfileslist]
options_widget = widgets.VBox(options, layout={'overflow': 'auto'})


def whentextischanged (change):
    """Dynamically update the widget experiments"""
    search_input = change['new']
    if search_input == '':
        # Reset search field, default to last 9 experiments
        new_options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in Allfileslist[-10:]]
    else:
        # Filter by search
        close_matches = [x for x in Allfileslist if search_input.upper() in x]
        ### magic code that generates only the match boxes ###
        new_options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in close_matches]

    options_widget.children = new_options

#Generate the vbox, search
multi_select = widgets.VBox([search_widget, options_widget])
search_widget.observe(whentextischanged, names='value')
#serve it up
multi_select
```

Is there any way generate only the checkboxes that are needed to speed things up?

**UPDATE**
I incorporate the answer of ac24 with some modification and it almost does what it needs to. The only thing it doesn't is show the defaults when the search box is empty in the beginning. Afterwards, clearing the search box shows the right behaviour.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

#Generate a dummy list
Allfileslist = ["{}".format(x) for x in range(600)]
#Search box + generate some checboxes
search_widget = widgets.Text(placeholder='Type for older experiments', description= 'Search:',value='')
experiments = {}
options_widget = widgets.VBox(layout={'overflow': 'auto'})
default_options = [widgets.Checkbox(description=eachfilename, value=False) for eachfilename in Allfileslist[-10:]]

def whentextischanged (change):
    """Dynamically update the widget experiments"""
    search_input = change['new']
    if search_input == '':
        # Reset search field, default to last 9 experiments
        new_options = default_options
    else:
        # Filter by search
        close_matches = [x for x in Allfileslist if search_input.lower() in x.lower()][:10]
        for name in close_matches:
            if name not in experiments:
                experiments[name] = widgets.Checkbox(description=name, value=False)
        new_options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in close_matches]

    options_widget.children = new_options

#Generate the vbox, search
multi_select = widgets.VBox([search_widget, options_widget])
search_widget.observe(whentextischanged, names='value')
multi_select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an empty dictionary first, then populating with checkboxes as you get closer to your desired choice of experiment.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

#Generate a dummy list
Allfileslist = ["{}".format(x) for x in range(600)]
#Search box + generate ALL the checkboxes, this seems to be the bottleneck
search_widget = widgets.Text(placeholder='Type for older experiments',                 description= 'Search:')
# experiments = {eachfilename: widgets.Checkbox(description=eachfilename, value=False) for eachfilename in Allfileslist}
experiments = {}
options_widget = widgets.VBox(layout={'overflow': 'auto'})


def whentextischanged (change):
    """Dynamically update the widget experiments"""
    search_input = change['new']
    if search_input == '':
        # Reset search field, default to last 9 experiments
        new_options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in Allfileslist[-10:]]
    else:
        # Filter by search
        close_matches = [x for x in Allfileslist if search_input.lower() in x.lower()][:10]
        for name in close_matches:
            if name not in experiments:
                experiments[name] = widgets.Checkbox(description=name, value=False)

        ### magic code that generates only the match boxes ###
        new_options = [experiments[eachfilename] for eachfilename in close_matches]

    options_widget.children = new_options

#Generate the vbox, search
multi_select = widgets.VBox([search_widget, options_widget])
search_widget.observe(whentextischanged, names='value')
#serve it up
multi_select
```

Then once you have chosen a few options, call  `[key for key, exp_check in exp_checkboxes.items() if exp_check.value]` to see the chosen values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I slightly modified your answer and it almost works. Just the default selection is not shown, any ideas?

Comment: Hacky as anything but put `whentextischanged({'new':''})` as the 2nd to last line before `display(multi_select)`?

Comment: Very hacky but unfortunately perfectly in tune with my usual coding standard. Thank you very much!